# Python csv.DictReader: parse string?

Tags: python, csv

I am downloading a CSV file directly from a URL using `requests`.

How can I parse the resulting string with `csv.DictReader`?

Right now I have this:

```
r = requests.get(url)
reader_list = csv.DictReader(r.text)
print reader_list.fieldnames
for row in reader_list:
    print row
```

But I just get `['r']` as the result of `fieldnames`, and then all kinds of weird things from `print row`.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

From the documentation of [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader), the first argument to [`csv.reader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) or [`csv.DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) is `csvfile` -

> *csvfile* can be any object which supports the [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) protocol and returns a string each time its `__next__()` method is called — [file objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object) and list objects are both suitable.

In your case when you give the string as the direct input for the `csv.DictReader()` , the `__next__()` call on that string only provides a single character, and hence that becomes the header, and then `__next__()` is continuously called to get each row.

Hence, you need to either provide an in-memory stream of strings using `io.StringIO`:

```
>>> import csv
>>> s = """a,b,c
... 1,2,3
... 4,5,6
... 7,8,9"""
>>> import io
>>> reader_list = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(s))
>>> print(reader_list.fieldnames)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for row in reader_list:
...     print(row)
... 
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
{'a': '4', 'b': '5', 'c': '6'}
{'a': '7', 'b': '8', 'c': '9'}
```

or a list of lines using [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines):

```
>>> reader_list = csv.DictReader(s.splitlines())
>>> print(reader_list.fieldnames)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> for row in reader_list:
...     print(row)
... 
{'a': '1', 'b': '2', 'c': '3'}
{'a': '4', 'b': '5', 'c': '6'}
{'a': '7', 'b': '8', 'c': '9'}
```

Comment: splitlines() FTW

Comment: The problem with using splitlines() is, if the content contains line breaks within a column (using quotes), it will break the line anyway.

Comment: As @augustomen has commented, you should explain that `splitlines` can break the record data line, since it can be inserted into a field by using quotes. If this is a problem, it should be stated. If the `csv` library can handle this, it should be also explained.