# b64decode on json import reading data incorrectly

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, csv, decode

I am importing json data from github for a class, and when I try to convert to a dictionary the values are not staying in key-value pairs.

Here is the import:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
import base64

response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/bsullins/data/contents/MonthlySales.csv')

response_json = json.loads(response.text)
csv_val = base64.b64decode(response_json['content'])

pp(csv_val)
```

The result of this has the original data, although I'm not sure what the "\r\n" delimiters are. Clearly it did not import correctly, as the strings cut off at different points than they should.

```
(b'month,sales\r\n2013-01-01,14236.9\r\n2013-02-01,4519.89\r\n2013-03-01,5569'
 b'1.01\r\n2013-04-01,28295.35\r\n2013-05-01,23648.29\r\n2013-06-01,34595.13\r'
 b'\n2013-07-01,33946.39\r\n2013-08-01,27909.47\r\n2013-09-01,81777.35\r\n2013'
 b'-10-01,31453.39\r\n2013-11-01,78628.72\r\n2013-12-01,69545.62\r\n2014-01-0'
 b'1,18174.08\r\n2014-02-01,11951.41\r\n2014-03-01,38726.25\r\n2014-04-01,341'
 b'95.21\r\n2014-05-01,30131.69\r\n2014-06-01,24797.29\r\n2014-07-01,28765.33'
```

When I later try to read the data with DictReader, it parses everything letter by letter:

```
import csv

csv_dict = csv.DictReader(str(csv_val))
dict_list = []

for a in csv_dict:
    dict_list.append(a):

for a in dict_list:
    print(a)
```

Here is the result:

```
OrderedDict([('b', "'")])
OrderedDict([('b', 'm')])
OrderedDict([('b', 'o')])
OrderedDict([('b', 'n')])
OrderedDict([('b', 't')])
OrderedDict([('b', 'h')])
OrderedDict([('b', ''), (None, [''])])
OrderedDict([('b', 's')])
OrderedDict([('b', 'a')])
OrderedDict([('b', 'l')])
OrderedDict([('b', 'e')])
OrderedDict([('b', 's')])
OrderedDict([('b', '\\')])
OrderedDict([('b', 'r')])
OrderedDict([('b', '\\')])
OrderedDict([('b', 'n')])
OrderedDict([('b', '2')])
OrderedDict([('b', '0')])
OrderedDict([('b', '1')])
OrderedDict([('b', '3')])
OrderedDict([('b', '-')])
OrderedDict([('b', '0')])
OrderedDict([('b', '1')])
OrderedDict([('b', '-')])
OrderedDict([('b', '0')])
OrderedDict([('b', '1')])
OrderedDict([('b', ''), (None, [''])])
OrderedDict([('b', '1')])
OrderedDict([('b', '4')])
OrderedDict([('b', '2')])
OrderedDict([('b', '3')])
OrderedDict([('b', '6')])
OrderedDict([('b', '.')])
OrderedDict([('b', '9')])
OrderedDict([('b', '\\')])
OrderedDict([('b', 'r')])
OrderedDict([('b', '\\')])
OrderedDict([('b', 'n')])
OrderedDict([('b', '2')])
OrderedDict([('b', '0')])
OrderedDict([('b', '1')])
OrderedDict([('b', '3')])
OrderedDict([('b', '-')])
OrderedDict([('b', '0')])
OrderedDict([('b', '2')])
OrderedDict([('b', '-')])
OrderedDict([('b', '0')])
OrderedDict([('b', '1')])
OrderedDict([('b', ''), (None, [''])])
OrderedDict([('b', '4')])
OrderedDict([('b', '5')])
OrderedDict([('b', '1')])
OrderedDict([('b', '9')])
OrderedDict([('b', '.')])
...
```

Comment: Are you required to use pprint? Or is this just something you personally want to use?

Comment: No, just using out of personal convenience, but the same thing happens with print(). Do you recommend not using it?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the api https://api.github.com/repos/bsullins/data/contents/MonthlySales.csv, and the response has a key,value

`download_url:"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bsullins/data/master/MonthlySales.csv"`

This url actually contains the raw format of the csv so lets use that, as it reduces the code as well.

```
from pprint import pprint as pp
import requests
import io
import csv
response = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bsullins/data/master/MonthlySales.csv')
csv_val = response.text
pp(csv_val)
csv_dict = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(csv_val))
dict_list = []

for a in csv_dict:
    dict_list.append(a)

for a in dict_list:
    print(a)
```

You need to use `StringIO` to parse string value of `csv_val` as csv needs  in-memory stream of the string. See [Python csv.DictReader: parse string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658115/python-csv-dictreader-parse-string)

Comment: Thanks for the help -I looked at the attached link. I'm not sure I understand "in-memory stream of the string (Using StringIO)." What does in-memory stream mean?

Comment: You can read the official docs for StringIO, it explains nicely.