# How to get csvreader's DictReader to process one line at a time?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, streaming

I am unzipping a very large CSV file in a memory-constrained environment. For this reason I unzip a line at a time like so:

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(temp_file.name) as zip_content:
    filename = zip_content.namelist()[0]
    with zip_content.open(filename, mode="r") as content:
        for line in content:
            print(line)
```

Which correctly yields each line as a byte array.

```
b'name,age,city\n'
b'John,12,Madrid\n'
...
```

I'd like to process these lines with a `csv.DictReader` so I can reliably access each field.

However, clearly I cannot create a new dict reader inside the loop for each line.

I'm tempted to just roll my own solution parsing the headers and then creating these dictionaries for each line, but I wonder if there is some quick way to leverage `DictReader`.

What is a way of accomplishing this while avoiding reading the entire file into memory first?

Comment: You can parse each line at a time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658115/python-csv-dictreader-parse-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [io.TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=textiowrapper#io.TextIOWrapper) to wrap the open zip entry then use `csv.DictReader` to read the CSV file line by line.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import csv
from io import TextIOWrapper

file_name = "test.zip"
with ZipFile(file_name) as zipObj:
    for info in zipObj.infolist():
        with zipObj.open(info.filename, "r") as zd:
         reader = csv.DictReader(TextIOWrapper(zd, "utf-8"))
            for row in reader:
                print(row)
```

For the sample CSV input, the output would be:

```
{'name': 'John', 'age': '12', 'city': 'Madrid'}
```

Comment: Works great, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
with zip_content.open(filename, mode="r") as content:
    header = next(content).decode('utf-8').strip().split(',')

    for line in content:
        line_io = io.StringIO(line.decode('utf-8'))
        reader = csv.DictReader(line_io, fieldnames=header)

        for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

Here you're only holding one line in memory at a time (plus the header), so it should be efficient for large CSV files.

Comment: Looks super promising! but I see `fieldnames` is assigned twice - once at first, and then for every line. And `line_io` is never used. Did you mean to do something with `line_io` instead within that inner loop?

Comment: I guess this is a part I'm struggling with - how to update the dict reader with each new line coming from the file?